# Change width/height UINavigationBar embedded in a Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Constraints can be assigned to **UINavigationBar** that is added manually to the view.

But when the **UINavigationBar** is added to a view when and the view is embedded in a Navigation Controller, I am not able to add constraints to the same.

My objective is to increase the height of the **UINavigationBar**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UINavigationBar** does not allow to assign constraints to itself. The only easy way that the height can be changed is by adding a space to the **prompt**  property.

To increase the the height of the **UINavigationBar** there are two steps:

1. Sub-class the **UINavigationBar** class and overriding the method that give the height to the **UINavigationBar**, this class thereafter needs to be assigned to the **NavBar** of the **Navigation Controller**

Note: All the views under that particular **Navigation Controller** will have the new height

Code Snippet:

```
class ModifiedNavBar: UINavigationBar {

override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {

let screenWidth =  UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

    let newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, 60)

    return newSize
   }

  }
```

> Note: The above step increases the height of the **NavBar** but it does not give you full customisation options. Adding a view gives you full control over the same.

2. Create a **view** programmatically and then adding it to the **UINavigationItem** (titleView) Outlet:

Code Snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

/*** UINavigationItem Outlet ***/
@IBOutlet weak var navbar: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 90))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 20))
    let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 20))

    /*** First Label ***/
    label.text = "Hello"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    view.addSubview(label)

    /***Second Label ***/
    label2.text = "Hello2"
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    view.addSubview(label2)

    self.navbar.titleView = view
}
```

> **Note**: If **prompt** is added to any of the **UINavigationItem** objects the size of the **NavBar** will increase

Comment: sizeThatFits: no longer works with iOS11 UINavigationBar subclasses. Apple Engineering have confirmed that this technique was never supported and with iOS11 changes sizeThatFits: is no longer consulted.