# Add UIView over Navigation Bar after Push Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have two **ViewControllers**. I want to add an **UIView** over the navigation bar.

I could add the **UIView** on top of the first navigation bar by creating an **UINavigationItem** Outlet and adding the **UIView** created programatically to the **UINavigationItem** outlet **titleView**.

Code Snippet (HomeVC - Fist ViewController):

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var homeNavigationItem: UINavigationItem!
let navBarView = UIView()
let topNavBarLabel = UILabel()
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

navBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 50.0)

topNavBarLabel.text = "Hello World"
topNavBarLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
topNavBarLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
topNavBarLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 10.0, width: screenWidth, height: 20.0)
navBarView.addSubview(topNavBarLabel)

homeNavigationItem.titleView = navBarView

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Screenshot Home View:

[image]

Now incase of the SecondVC I am trying to do the same thing after the **Push** Segue.

Code Snippet (DetailVC - Second ViewController):

```
class DetailsVC: UIViewController {

let navBarView = UIView()
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let navBarTopLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

navBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 50.0, width: screenWidth, height: 50.0)
navBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

navBarTopLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 10.0, width: screenWidth, height: 20.0)
navBarTopLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
navBarTopLabel.text = "Details Hello"
navBarTopLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

navBarView.addSubview(navBarTopLabel)

self.view.addSubview(navBarView)
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: navBarView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Screenshot Details View:

[image]

Storyboard Screenshot:

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

View Hierarchy:

[image: View Hierarchy]

> **Note:** I deliberately assigned an Y-position to the view more than 0, to be sure that the view is being created

But as I am not able to create an **UINavigationItem**, I am adding the programmatically created view to the view and even trying to bring the **subView** to the front.

> **Note:** Yes, the size of the **UINavigationBar** has been increased, please refer here: [Change width/height UINavigationBar embedded in a Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343381/change-width-height-uinavigationbar-embedded-in-a-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the variable defined for `UIViewController`

```
public var navigationItem: UINavigationItem { get }
```

From the docs:

> Created on-demand so that a view controller may customize its navigation appearance.

So in each subclass of `UIViewController` in `viewDidLoad` you can just do

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = navBarView
```